# Cartthrob not returning after transaction with SagePay

Tags: cartthrob, sagepay

I am having an issue with sage. Transactions are going through and money is being taken no problem, but it isn't returning to the desired return= param.

I have tested with PayPal and all works fine. Has anyone else had an issue like this? Any solutions out there?

Cheers

Comment: What param are you expecting? Which integration method are you using? Is the shopper reaching the destination/success/redirect URL correctly? Email feedback@sagepay.com and I can take a look at your transactions for you. Would need to know the vendor name and the txid and/or txcode. Quote this forum post too so I can pick up your query. Kind regards Sage Pay Support

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The return param is where i want the customer to return to after checkout. So return="cart/confirm". I'll email. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

have you updated the extload.php inside /themes/third_party/cartthrob/lib ?

Comment: Ahhhh. Steven, you maybe a bacon saver!I using and MSM site and there was a little bit to edit regarding that. Currently however, I am using the same themes folder (Which should be fine), but what about the shortname for the site? If CT is using this file on site2 and the config is using site1's shortname, will that not be an issue?

Comment: Oh, just noticed in the comments in extload.php that it is used for 'offsite' payments. I am using SagePay Direct so my site is sending details to them. I'll have a play and see if it makes a difference. Thanks for the heads up though.